# What does "+1" mean in the following Qlik expression

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am assuming the following expression means sum of sales for year 2009 and country Sweden, but I am not sure why +1 is being used, is it used as separator or it has any special meaning?

> Sum({$<Year={2009}>+1<Country={'Sweden'}>} Sales)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1` in set analysis indicates that the calculation will ignore all selections made - `returns a full set of data irrespective of user selections`

In your case I can read the calculation like this:

Give me the **union** sum of `Sales` for:

- `Year={2009}` - all sales for 2009. Respect the selections made (apart from `Year`)
- `1<Country={'Sweden'}` - sales for `Sweden` but as if there are no selections applied across the app (if there are any selections made - ignore them)

Helpful links:

- [Set Modifiers](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2022/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-modifiers.htm#) (scroll down to `Forced exclusion` section)
- [Set analysis and set expressions](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2022/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-analysis-expressions.htm) (scroll down to `Operators` section)